# Which statistical test should I use to see difference between averages of two different samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I'm diabetic and the Dr. prescribed me new medicine. So I recorded glucose samples before I started the medicine (PRE) and after I started the medicine (POST). Now that I have decent amount of data accumulated I'm wondering which test to use to see if there is a significant change in the glucose levels.

Do you know which statistical test I should use to see if there was a significant improvement?

```
PRE_POST | Marker        | Avg glucose | Sample Size | min glucose | max glucose 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POST     | Fasting       | 167.90      |11           | 120         | 210
POST     | Not Fasting   | 134.68      |22           | 93          | 202
PRE      | Fasting       | 190.75      |24           | 145         | 294
PRE      | Not Fasting   | 169.62      |24           | 100         | 358
```